# return false or e.preventdefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have one form with one text box and i give 50 char limit in that with below script

Its working fine.

but when i click on submit its will get submit after show a alert message
its should not be submitted

```
function charLimit(e) {
    var value = $("#concept_name").val();
    if(value.length > 50){
      alert("Maximum limit is 50 character");
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
     } 
<%= f.text_area :name, rows:1 , :required => true, :onkeypress=> "charLimit()" %>

<button type="submit" onclick="charLimit()">submit</button>
```

please help me to find what is wrong in my script.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I read your question wrong at first.

Comment: let me try this first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use onclick with button declaration because it's like tight coupling coding standards. Instead do it like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitBtn">submit</button>

$("#submitBtn").on('click',function(event){

    var value = $("#concept_name").val();

    if(value.length > 50){
       alert("Maximum limit is 50 character");
       event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break the `submit` event, you have to add the handler to the `form` element, not the `button`. Otherwise you only handle and break the button, not the form action.

```
<form action="foo.html" onsubmit="return charLimit()">
    <!-- content -->
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Simple live example: https://jsfiddle.net/ukynbn0s/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add click event:

```js
$("button").click(function(){ // add button click event
    var value = $("#concept_name").val();
    if(value.length > 50){
      alert("Maximum limit is 50 character");
      return false; // it will not submit form if return false
    }else{
      alert("Form will be submitted");
      return true;
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <textarea id="concept_name" name="concept_name"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```